# How I can I make VBA macro force Run As Administrator

Tags: malware, windows, antimalware, windows-permissions

I'm trying to perform Reflective Dll Injection via VBA macro. The main idea behind using Reflective Dll Injection is to bypass Windows Defender as dropping an dll onto the disk seems very loud.

The problem is that I would like my VBA macro to run with Administrator privileges. **I want excel/word vba macro to force Run As Administrator UAC message** as at the moment after user double click on the document the malicious actions are performed quietly but the ones that require Administrator privs fail.

The only answer I've found on internet was:

`Shell "runas.exe /user:administrator ""Your-App.exe""", vbNormalFocus`

which seems to be super loud as it spawns new process (Shell) and requires an executable on disk.

Thanks!